# Feeds: is it possible to resume a partially finished (and locked) import job?

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting

Yesterday I tried importing a very large (15K+) number of nodes (some with files attachments) using the feeds module (CSV mode). After a while, the feeds module gave me a timeout error, and now when I get back to the import page, the "status" block reads `Importing - 5 % complete` and the import button at the bottom of the page is disabled and reads `Importing (5%)`. On the "Log" tab, there are no messages of any kind.

Is there any way for me to resume this job?

From what I see, my only options are:

- unlock the job (via the "Unlock" tab)
- delete the created items (via the "Delete items" tab)

Since the feeds module seems to know that the job is only partially done (and which nodes where already processed), I find it a bit strange that there are no options to resume it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Also interested in this. Did you get an answer elsewhere?

Comment: @Collins: unfortunately no...

Comment: This is a bug in Feeds: when importing CSV files using the HTTP Fetcher the CSV file will be saved as a temporary file. Drupal deletes temporary files after six hours. I'm working on fixing this bug: https://www.drupal.org/node/1029102